# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and conda environments

Tags: python, sql-server, anaconda

According to [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/python-interoperability?view=sql-server-2017):

"Installation of SQL Server 2017 Machine Learning Services adds the Anaconda distribution of Python. Specifically, the Anaconda 3 installers are used, based on the Anaconda 4.3 branch. The expected Python level for SQL Server 2017 is Python 3.5."

I read quite a few documents linked from this site, but I couldn't find any answers to these two questions:

1. Can one define different conda environments on the server where Machine Learning Services are activated?
2. If (1) is possible, how can someone define which conda environment should be used when calling the `sp_execute_external_script` stored procedure?

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Python environment you can use from sp_execute_external_script is the one installed with Machine Learning Services. It is unfortunately not possible to point to a different Conda environment.